# Fail to execute AsyncTask correctly

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have experienced some problem while executing my `AsyncTask` in a Android Fragment class.
In a `onClick` method I had called my execute with following code `new BackgroundTaskPost().execute();`

I have tried to form my `AsyncTask` in different ways, but none of them works.

My latest try is following:

```
public class BackgroundTaskPost extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        SharedPreferences preferenceLogin = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(loginPreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        userName = preferenceLogin.getString("UserName", null);
        password = preferenceLogin.getString("Password", null);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        radioId1 = sharedPreferences.getString("check1", " ");
        radioId2 = sharedPreferences.getString("check2", " ");
        radioId3 = sharedPreferences.getString("check3", " ");
        radioId4 = sharedPreferences.getString("check4", " ");
        radioId5 = sharedPreferences.getString("check5", " ");
        radioId6 = sharedPreferences.getString("check6", " ");
        radioId7 = sharedPreferences.getString("check7", " ");
        radioId8 = sharedPreferences.getString("check8", " ");
        radioId9 = sharedPreferences.getString("check9", " ");
        radioId10 = sharedPreferences.getString("check10", " ");
        radioId11 = sharedPreferences.getString("check11", " ");
        //fev1 = pref.getFloat("Result", 0);

        outputs = new Outputs[13];
        outputs[0] = new Outputs("387.WEIGHT", "Float", "25.3");
        outputs[1] = new Outputs("383.FIELD", "String", radioId1);
        outputs[2] = new Outputs("384.FIELD", "String", radioId2);
        outputs[3] = new Outputs("381.FIELD", "String", radioId3);
        outputs[4] = new Outputs("389.FIELD", "String", radioId4);
        outputs[5] = new Outputs("388.LF#FEV1", "Float", "0.99");
        outputs[6] = new Outputs("390.FIELD", "String", radioId5);
        outputs[7] = new Outputs("378.FIELD", "String", radioId6);
        outputs[8] = new Outputs("379.FIELD", "String", radioId7);
        outputs[9] = new Outputs("380.FIELD", "String", radioId8);
        outputs[10] = new Outputs("382.FIELD", "String", radioId9);
        outputs[11] = new Outputs("385.FIELD", "String", radioId10);
        outputs[12] = new Outputs("386.FIELD", "String", radioId11);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        postRequest = new HttpPostRequest(userName, password);

        String content = postRequest.postQuestionnaire(59, "Månedkontrol", "1.0", outputs);
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

My problem is that I never come to the `onPostExecute`, because the app crashes, following error occurs in the logcat.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 500
        at com.example.OpenTeleStandaloneApplication.HttpIntegration.HttpPostRequest.postRequest(HttpPostRequest.java:55)
        at com.example.OpenTeleStandaloneApplication.HttpIntegration.HttpPostRequest.postQuestionnaire(HttpPostRequest.java:104)
        at com.example.OpenTeleStandaloneApplication.ApplicationInterface.cfqrlunge7$BackgroundTaskPost.doInBackground(cfqrlunge7.java:169)
        at com.example.OpenTeleStandaloneApplication.ApplicationInterface.cfqrlunge7$BackgroundTaskPost.doInBackground(cfqrlunge7.java:128)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I can tell that I have several times tried to use the same code in a console application in Eclipse, where it works very fine without problems. So I can conclude that the problems comes in the `AsyncTask`.

The HttpRequest:

```
public String getInput(int id, String name, String version, Outputs[] outputs){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

    String retVal = "{\"QuestionnaireId\":" + id + "," +
            "\"date\":\"" + dateFormat.format(new Date()) + "\"," +
            "\"name\":\"" + name + "\"," +
            "\"version\":\"" + version + "\"," +
            "\"output\":[";
    for (int i = 0; i < outputs.length; i++) {
        retVal += "{\"name\":\""+ outputs[i].getName() +
                "\",\"type\":\"" + outputs[i].getType() +
                "\",\"value\":" + outputs[i].getValue() +
                "}";
        if(i < outputs.length - 1)
            retVal += ",";
    }
    retVal += "]}";

    return retVal;
}

public String postQuestionnaire(int id, String name, String version, Outputs[] outputs){
    return postRequest("rest/questionnaire/listing", getInput(id, name, version, outputs));
}
```

Hopefully anyone can help me, I have spent a lot of time during this problem the last two days. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your problem is that HTTP error code 500 you are getting in your `doInBackground()` code. Can you post your code for your `HttpPostRequest` class?

Comment: @drschultz 500 is a server side error.

Comment: @TylerSebastian - Yes, I know that. And it's what's causing his error, as stated in the output. His HttpPostRequest object is running a method that is failing because of the server's 500 response, which is why I was asking for the HttpPostRequest code.

Answer (score 0):

An observation - there are several very good network / rest libraries out there, so there's really no reason to roll your own with the low-level HttpRequest and friends. Your problems handling a simple HTTP 500 error underscore that.

Also, despite getting a lot of "positive press", an AsyncTask is an awful place to try to do network access. I'd argue that its a construct that just shouldn't be used at all because it's not Activity-lifecycle aware, but I digress.

I suggest that you check out one of the aforementioned libraries, for example Retrofit or Volley. They will give you a framework to work in that handles many of these issues rather than re-inventing the wheel.